# Can anyone help me translate this Javascript code line the Drupal Way?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert this code line (it focuses the cursor to the first input of a form) to Drupal behaviourism. Can anyone help me put it the Drupal bushido way?

```
jQuery("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

Becomes

```
Drupal.behaviors.focustextfield = function(context) {
  $("input:text:visible:first:not(.focustextfield-procd)", context).addClass("focustextfield-procd").focus();
}
```